# Conditional probability of the complement

Tags: probability

> Prove that if $(P(A|B) \geq P(A)$, that $P(A^C|B^C) \leq P(A^C)$, given that $P(B^C) >0$.

I'm having problem solving this question because I don't know how to write $P(A^C \cap B^C)$ differently using disjoint sets. Can anybody chime in?

Comment: Well, your fundamental building blocks are $AB,A^CB,AB^C,$ and $A^CB^C$.  So you don't need to decompose $A^CB^C$, you just need to decompose your other expressions.

Comment: In other words, you don't want to rewrite $P(A^C\cap B^C)$, you want to rewrite $P(A^C)$ as  $P(A^C\cap B^C)+P(A^C\cap B)$.

Comment: I think you may have transcribed this problem incorrectly, btw.

Comment: Unless I'm badly mistaken, the version you have only holds when $A$ and $B$ are independent (and thus $P(A|B)=P(A)$).  I think you've either got one of the $\le$ or $\ge$ pointing the wrong way, or one too many/few complements (i.e. $A^C$ where it should be $A$, etc.).

Comment: If we start with $$P(A|B)\gt P(A)$$ multiplying both sides by $-1$ and adding $1$ gives $$1-P(A|B)=P(A^C|B) \lt 1-P(A)=P(A^C)$$ Since $P(A^C)=P(A^C|B)P(B)+P(A^C|B^C)P(B^C)$ is a weighted average of $P(A^C|B)$ and $P(A^C|B^C)$, this implies that $$P(A^C|B^C)\gt P(A^C)$$ So the statement as given is false unless $P(A)=P(A|B)$

Comment: @GabrielBurns You are correct, I misread the problem. It says either prove or disprove, but all the previous exercises where correct so I forgot about the "disprove" part, I'm sorry.